# Memory leak through UnmarshallingContext

Tags: java, out-of-memory, eclipse-mat, java-memory-leaks, java-heap

I've upgraded a Java microservice from Java 8 to Java 17, and I am encountering an "Out of Memory" (OOM) issue when processing bulk records. In heap dumps, the suspect is identified as `com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext` loaded by `org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader`, occupying 22.54%. I haven't found any relevant information in the heap dump related to my microservice.

[image: Problem suspect]

And I have hit a dead end trying to find the memory leak. Is there any other reason which might be causing the issue?

Comment: Do you have a stack trace of that OOM?

Comment: No, I don't have